# Simulating a rope with drake

Tags: drake

I find that there is DeformableModel class in the drake documentation and I have seen a video used the rope in drake. I want to simulate a rope with a payload but I don't know how to create a rope. Could you please give me some advice or examples. Thank you.

Comment: Right now Drake's deformable simulation only supports volumetric objects. Codimensional objects (cloth, rope, etc) are not supported yet. Depending on your use case, you could model your rope as a thin and long volumetric deformable box/cylinder, but that's a bad idea more often than not. The rope simulation you've seen is probably a chain of rigid bodies connected possibly by ball joints.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Xuchen -- we have definitely simulated ropes in Drake before using a series rigid links.

- If you connect them by ball joints, then you can model [damping](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1multibody_1_1_ball_rpy_joint.html#aad91b55e6b714db4ba96190e6fab07ac).
- If you also want to model the (linear and torsional) stiffness of the rope, then you might prefer to connect the links with our [`LinearBushingRollPitchYaw`](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1multibody_1_1_linear_bushing_roll_pitch_yaw.html) elements, which models those stiffness directly.

The bushing element will be a bit more expensive to simulate, and one always needs to understand that very large stiffness or damping coefficients will require smaller simulation time steps (again slower simulation).